# Transactional smtp email service sender

Tags: wordpress, smtp, mailgun

Unfortunately, I seem to be very confuse about how transactional email services work (or smtp servers in general).

I set up my WordPress site to send email using Mailgun as the mailer. I have configured in mailgun with my own domain, so the sender email address ("from") is test@mydomain.com.

Mydomain.com also has its own inbox in gmail. This is where I'm confused. Does the email sent through mailgun would have any record in the gmail server? or these are two different things and is only the domain that is used to send an email, No connection to the gmail server at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email sent through mailgun would not be recorded by the gmail server.

Mailgun is acting as an independent mail transfer agent, via SMTP, for your WordPress emails.

Here's [an article on how to forward you mailgun emails to your gmail](https://letswp.io/mailgun-forward-email-on-your-domain-to-gmail/).